# React Native -- Possible to console.log in return()?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm debugging a `<View>` element and want to ensure a variable is being returned correctly. How would I `console.log(element)` so I can view it in the console and ensure it's correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be a number of tricks to do this, but I would advise storing what you want to return in a variable, and then log the value you are interested before the return, like this:

```
render() {
    let element = <MyElement></MyElement>
    console.log(element)
    let wrappingView = <View>{element}</View>

    return wrappingView;
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Yes, it is possible.

```js
return(
  <View>
    {console.log(element)}
  </View>
)
```